# Selenium : I have a webpage where two elements have same Xpath, even index doesn't separate them apart

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, xpath

They both get identified when the index is [1], and for index [2] nothing gets identified. The only thing which separates them is that the first popup has `display:none`, and the other popup has `display:block`, but they do not get a play in deciding this particular fields because Xpath, because these fields are fetched from some different source.

Alas, these divs even though they have same elements, they have a document attribute so, the Xpath for these don't start with this div, but after the part of the document. I have racked my brain all I could, I could give you a vague idea of how the code looks like below.

The code looks like:

```
<div name='some-name' style="display:none;">
  ...
  <!document>
  <div id='some-id'>
    ....
    <button name='some-name-2'>some-button-name</button>
    ....
  </div>
  ...
</div>
<div name='some-name' style="display:block;">
  ...
  <!document>
  <div is='some-id'>
    ....
    <button name='some-name-2'>some-button-name</button>
    ....
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

So both of their Xpath looks something like:

[id='some-id']/...../button

Giving ([id='some-id']/...../button)[1] fetches both the elements.

Giving ([id='some-id']/...../button)[2] fetches none of them.

### Update

I had two iframes in this case, and since I had to switch between them, it was not getting detected. Thanks, I fixed this.

Comment: I doubt that you are getting both elements with `([id='some-id']/...../button)[1]` given that this xpath can't return more than one element. Since your html has some `<!document>`, your issue is likely due to a frame. Search for how to handle a frame with Selenium.

Comment: Why not test for the style of the containing div as well, if that's all that's different?

Comment: actually, it doesn't get detected at all, the style doesn't come as a root, it ends everything before that <!document> tab

Comment: Are there literally four periods in a row in your XPath selector? Or were you using that to show that there were intervening tags like you show in the code section? Please edit the question so that it is showing the exact XPath you are using.

Comment: @user8507721 Make a list of elements...Selenium will take care of rest e.g. in your case if xpath is common & returns both elements...create a list and iterate through one by one ...hope this will resolve.

Comment: //*[@id="app"]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/button this is the exact Xpath, and tried, (//*[@id="app"]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/button)[2] not working //*[@id="app"][2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/button not working...

Comment: Is making a list as in using indexed values? Coz that's what I am saying, index is not working

Comment: Can you get us more of the _HTML DOM_ ? Unaltered, formatted, textbased?

Comment: Which one does _Selenium_ chooses using `([id='some-id']/...../button)[1] fetches both the elements` when you execute your tests?

Comment: okay thank you guys, actually it had two iframes and I needed to switch between them... It was so confusing, since they both had same Xpath...

Answer (score 0):

The way your Xpath reads is to find the element with `id='some-id'` and then find the first or second button within that. If you change it so that the `[1]` and `[2]` are placed after the `[id='some-id']` rather than at the end of the path you can choose to find the first or second `[id='some-id']`, and then the button within that element.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the two elements are actually one element, then there will always be XPath expressions that select one and not the other. In fact, there are an infinite number of such expressions. The trick is in finding a good XPath expression, and that depends on how much of the page content is fixed, and how much is variable (if the data is completely fixed, then you don't even need to read it, because you already know everything about it).

I think your inference that the subscripts [1] and [2] don't work is incorrect. It would be useful to know what expressions you actually used, because what you have written in your post:

`([id='some-id']/...../button)[1]`

is not a valid XPath expression at all.

Comment: //*[@id="some-app"]/.../button I tried copying the entire Xpath by google developer, copy-> xpath, still this detects both the elements, adding an index both of them get detected in the first indexed element, and none get detected in the [2] index.

Comment: It's hard to debug your code when you don't show your actual code, but I strongly suspect that the parentheses in your original version were not actually there. You want `(/a/b/c)[1]` and `(/a/b/c)[2]`, not `/a/b/c[1]` and `/a/b/c[2]`

Comment: The exact Xpath is //*[@id="app"]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/button, I have tried (//*[@id="app"]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/button)[2] and as suggested above tried //*[@id="app"][2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/button not working, both the elements get detected in the index [1]

Comment: And is iframe being there an issue?

Comment: I've no idea how Selenium handles iframes. It's always possible of course that Selenium is getting this wrong: I'm answering from the perspective of the XPath spec, not the Selenium implementation.